# Eclipse NEON Running Locally - Testing javaScript - Replace File While Running

Tags: javascript, eclipse, testing, eclipse-neon

Testing is really slow going for me in Eclipse. Deploy -> log into my site -> navigate to the appropriate screen, etc. While running locally, I am connecting to an external Dev database which doesn't have much horsepower. Total turn-around can be from 5-15 minutes depending on the day. Find out a quote is in the wrong place, rinse and repeat...

My question is this - Is there a way to replace a page on the fly while running locally?  This way I can fix the error, replace the single page, hit refresh in the browser and continue with the updated page? If so, where is the file being stored on the hard drive when Apache is running?

Sorry if this is a silly question, back in the old days I could do this all the time.  Just getting frustrated over here because I spend 5% of my time writing code and 95% going back and forth testing it because of the slow turn around.

Comment: The answer is "yes you can", but it depends on how you're bundling and deploying the app. Just find where the JS file is coming from and you can either directly hack that one to see the changes immediately (but have to copy them to the main file) or, even better, you can set up something to monitor the dev directory and on change, copy the files to the deployed directory. An even better thing you can do is set up unit tests with Jasmine or whatever, so you don't even need to go to a page for the most part.

Comment: Thanks, I figured there was a way. My biggest stumbling block was trying to figure out where localhost was running on my PC through Eclipse. I checked the various xml files and nothing jumped out at me. I finally kicked off my server, did a file search for one of the files on my C drive, and looked for the out of place directory. I managed to change a file there, refreshed my webpage and sure enough it worked!  I wish I would have dug into this much sooner...!